# SSH Access on Github

Tags: git, github

I recently changed the name of my github repository. After changing the naming, I have reconfigured my remote url to the new URL. 
But after the name change, my push and pull requests are not working. 
Every push/pull request returns the following error

```
"ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."
```

I have tried re-initiating my git repository and there was no change. 
i have also checked SSH connection using

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

and it returns the following message

```
Hi [user]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: I would suggest to generate a new private key:[generate key Github](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Comment: SSH is looking for a host named `github`. However, the GitHub server is called `github.com`, not `github`. Double-check your remote names and your SSH configuration.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I added a new remote repository and initiated another local git folder for it. The pull/[push requests via SSH works fine for the new repository.
It is just that, it is not working for the renamed repository.

Comment: As you can clearly see from the error message you posted, SSH is looking for a host named `github`. However, the GitHub server is called `github.com`, not `github`. Double-check your remote names in the renamed repository as well as your SSH configuration, to make sure that they refer to `github.com`, not `github`.